# border-radius: 50% not working | CSS/HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Point of this is to set the position of the div to the mouse as a added effect, it was supposed to have a radius, but it didn't work:

```js
let inner_circle = document.getElementById("inner_circle");

window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(mouse) {
  inner_circle.style.transform = `translate(${mouse.clientX}px, ${mouse.clientY}px)`; // sets the position of the inner circle to the mouse
});
```

```css
#inner_circle{
    margin-left: -3px;
    margin-top: -3px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 1px solid #703be7;
    border-radius: 50%; //<- doesn't work
    font-size: 1px;
    background-color: #703be7;
    width: 6px;
    width: 6px;
    z-index: 1000001;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="inner_circle"></div>
```

Comment: Read your CSS out loud! `width: 6px;
    width: 6px;`

Comment: @epascarello easy rep for everyone ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you meant height on the second line here and this makes it a problem

```
#inner_circle{
width: 6px;
width: 6px;
}
```

so just change it to height:

```
#inner_circle{
width: 6px;
height: 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change your css. width: 6px;width: 6px; to width: 6px;height: 6px;**

```js
let inner_circle = document.getElementById("inner_circle");

window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(mouse) {
  inner_circle.style.transform = `translate(${mouse.clientX}px, ${mouse.clientY}px)`; // sets the position of the inner circle to the mouse
});
```

```css
#inner_circle{
    margin-left: -3px;
    margin-top: -3px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 1px solid #703be7;
    border-radius: 50%; //<- doesn't work
    font-size: 1px;
    background-color: #703be7;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    z-index: 1000001;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inner_circle" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></div>
```